# py2neo Issue: ConnectionUnavailable: Cannot open connection to ConnectionProfile('bolt://localhost:7687')

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I am trying to replicate this example on neo4j desktop:

https://stellargraph.readthedocs.io/en/stable/demos/connector/neo4j/load-cora-into-neo4j.html

I am able to reproduce everything until I get to the following line:

```
import py2neo
default_host = os.environ.get("STELLARGRAPH_NEO4J_HOST")

# Create the Neo4j Graph database object; the arguments can be edited to specify location and authentication

graph = py2neo.Graph(host=default_host, port=None, user=None, password=None)
```

I have tried the following attempts to create the neo4j database object:

```
#1
default_host = os.environ.get("StellarGraph")
graph = py2neo.Graph(host=default_host, port=None, user=None, password=None)

#2
uri = 'bolt://localhost:7687'
graph = Graph(uri, auth=("neo4j", "password"), port= 7687, secure=True)

#3
uri = uri = 'bolt://localhost:7687'
graph = Graph(uri, auth=("neo4j", "password"), port= 7687, secure=True, name= "StellarGraph")
```

However, each time I attempt this, it results in some variation of this error:

```
    IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/__init__.py:806, in ConnectionPool.acquire(self, force_reset, can_overfill)
    804 try:
    805     # Plan A: select a free connection from the pool
--> 806     cx = self._free_list.popleft()
    807 except IndexError:

IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/wiring.py:62, in Wire.open(cls, address, timeout, keep_alive, on_broken)
     61 try:
---> 62     s.connect(address)
     63 except (IOError, OSError) as error:

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

WireError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/bolt.py:355, in Bolt.open(cls, profile, user_agent, on_release, on_broken)
    354 try:
--> 355     wire = cls._connect(profile, on_broken=on_broken)
    356     protocol_version = cls._handshake(wire)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/bolt.py:369, in Bolt._connect(cls, profile, on_broken)
    368 log.debug("[#%04X] C: (Dialing <%s>)", 0, profile.address)
--> 369 wire = Wire.open(profile.address, keep_alive=True, on_broken=on_broken)
    370 local_port = wire.local_address.port_number

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/wiring.py:64, in Wire.open(cls, address, timeout, keep_alive, on_broken)
     63 except (IOError, OSError) as error:
---> 64     raise_from(WireError("Cannot connect to %r" % (address,)), error)
     65 return cls(s, on_broken=on_broken)

File <string>:3, in raise_from(value, from_value)

WireError: Cannot connect to IPv4Address(('localhost', 7687))

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ConnectionUnavailable                     Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/myname/Project1/graph_import.ipynb Cell 13' in <cell line: 2>()
      1 uri = 'bolt://localhost:7687'
----> 2 graph = Graph(uri, auth=("neo4j", "mypass"), port= 7687, secure=True, name= "StellarGraph")

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/database.py:288, in Graph.__init__(self, profile, name, **settings)
    287 def __init__(self, profile=None, name=None, **settings):
--> 288     self.service = GraphService(profile, **settings)
    289     self.__name__ = name
    290     self.schema = Schema(self)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/database.py:119, in GraphService.__init__(self, profile, **settings)
    116 if connector_settings["init_size"] is None and not profile.routing:
    117     # Ensures credentials are checked on construction
    118     connector_settings["init_size"] = 1
--> 119 self._connector = Connector(profile, **connector_settings)
    120 self._graphs = {}

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/__init__.py:960, in Connector.__init__(self, profile, user_agent, init_size, max_size, max_age, routing_refresh_ttl)
    958 else:
    959     self._router = None
--> 960 self._add_pools(*self._initial_routers)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/__init__.py:982, in Connector._add_pools(self, *profiles)
    980     continue
    981 log.debug("Adding connection pool for profile %r", profile)
--> 982 pool = ConnectionPool.open(
    983     profile,
    984     user_agent=self._user_agent,
    985     init_size=self._init_size,
    986     max_size=self._max_size,
    987     max_age=self._max_age,
    988     on_broken=self._on_broken)
    989 self._pools[profile] = pool

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/__init__.py:649, in ConnectionPool.open(cls, profile, user_agent, init_size, max_size, max_age, on_broken)
    627 """ Create a new connection pool, with an option to seed one
    628 or more initial connections.
    629 
   (...)
    646     scheme
    647 """
    648 pool = cls(profile, user_agent, max_size, max_age, on_broken)
--> 649 seeds = [pool.acquire() for _ in range(init_size or cls.default_init_size)]
    650 for seed in seeds:
    651     seed.release()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/__init__.py:649, in <listcomp>(.0)
    627 """ Create a new connection pool, with an option to seed one
    628 or more initial connections.
    629 
   (...)
    646     scheme
    647 """
    648 pool = cls(profile, user_agent, max_size, max_age, on_broken)
--> 649 seeds = [pool.acquire() for _ in range(init_size or cls.default_init_size)]
    650 for seed in seeds:
    651     seed.release()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/__init__.py:813, in ConnectionPool.acquire(self, force_reset, can_overfill)
    807 except IndexError:
    808     if self._has_capacity() or can_overfill:
    809         # Plan B: if the pool isn't full, open
    810         # a new connection. This may raise a
    811         # ConnectionUnavailable exception, which
    812         # should bubble up to the caller.
--> 813         cx = self._connect()
    814         if cx.supports_multi():
    815             self._supports_multi = True

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/__init__.py:764, in ConnectionPool._connect(self)
    761 def _connect(self):
    762     """ Open and return a new connection.
    763     """
--> 764     cx = Connection.open(self.profile, user_agent=self.user_agent,
    765                          on_release=lambda c: self.release(c),
    766                          on_broken=lambda msg: self.__on_broken(msg))
    767     self._server_agent = cx.server_agent
    768     return cx

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/__init__.py:174, in Connection.open(cls, profile, user_agent, on_release, on_broken)
    172 if profile.protocol == "bolt":
    173     from py2neo.client.bolt import Bolt
--> 174     return Bolt.open(profile, user_agent=user_agent,
    175                      on_release=on_release, on_broken=on_broken)
    176 elif profile.protocol == "http":
    177     from py2neo.client.http import HTTP

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/bolt.py:364, in Bolt.open(cls, profile, user_agent, on_release, on_broken)
    362     return bolt
    363 except (TypeError, WireError) as error:
--> 364     raise_from(ConnectionUnavailable("Cannot open connection to %r" % profile), error)

File <string>:3, in raise_from(value, from_value)

ConnectionUnavailable: Cannot open connection to ConnectionProfile('bolt+s://localhost:7687')
```

I have also tried variations on this fix as well, but had the same error:

[ISSUE IN CONNECTING py2neo v4 to my neo4j server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54364980/issue-in-connecting-py2neo-v4-to-my-neo4j-server)

I appreciate any help resolving this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this with the following syntax:

```
graph = Graph('neo4j://localhost:7687', user="neo4j", password="999")
```

However, I am now having an issue with the following block:

```
empty_db_query = """
MATCH(n) DETACH
DELETE(n)
"""
tx = graph.begin(autocommit=True)
tx.evaluate(empty_db_query)
```

For the newer version of py2neo, the graph.begin argument takes readonly = F instead of autocommit = True, but in any case, I have this error now:

```
    ServiceUnavailable                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/myname/Project1/graph_import.ipynb Cell 13' in <cell line: 6>()
      1 empty_db_query = """
      2     MATCH(n) DETACH
      3     DELETE(n)
      4     """
----> 6 tx = graph.begin(readonly=False)
      7 tx.evaluate(empty_db_query)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/database.py:351, in Graph.begin(self, readonly)
    340 def begin(self, readonly=False,
    341           # after=None, metadata=None, timeout=None
    342           ):
    343     """ Begin a new :class:`~py2neo.Transaction`.
    344 
    345     :param readonly: if :py:const:`True`, will begin a readonly
   (...)
    349     removed. Use the 'auto' method instead.*
    350     """
--> 351     return Transaction(self, autocommit=False, readonly=readonly,
    352                        # after, metadata, timeout
    353                        )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/database.py:915, in Transaction.__init__(self, graph, autocommit, readonly)
    913     self._ref = None
    914 else:
--> 915     self._ref = self._connector.begin(self.graph.name, readonly=readonly,
    916                                       # after, metadata, timeout
    917                                       )
    918 self._readonly = readonly
    919 self._closed = False

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/__init__.py:1357, in Connector.begin(self, graph_name, readonly)
   1345 def begin(self, graph_name, readonly=False,
   1346           # after=None, metadata=None, timeout=None
   1347           ):
   1348     """ Begin a new explicit transaction.
   1349 
   1350     :param graph_name:
   (...)
   1355     :raises Failure: if the server signals a failure condition
   1356     """
-> 1357     cx = self._acquire(graph_name)
   1358     try:
   1359         return cx.begin(graph_name, readonly=readonly,
   1360                         # after=after, metadata=metadata, timeout=timeout
   1361                         )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/__init__.py:1111, in Connector._acquire(self, graph_name, readonly)
   1109     return self._acquire_ro(graph_name)
   1110 else:
-> 1111     return self._acquire_rw(graph_name)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/__init__.py:1203, in Connector._acquire_rw(self, graph_name)
   1199 # TODO: exit immediately if the server/cluster is in readonly mode
   1201 while True:
-> 1203     ro_profiles, rw_profiles = self._get_profiles(graph_name, readonly=False)
   1204     if rw_profiles:
   1205         # There is at least one writer, so collect the pools
   1206         # for those writers. In all implementations to date,
   1207         # a Neo4j cluster will only ever contain at most one
   1208         # writer (per database). But this algorithm should
   1209         # still survive if that changes.
   1210         pools = [pool for profile, pool in list(self._pools.items())
   1211                  if profile in rw_profiles]

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/__init__.py:1016, in Connector._get_profiles(self, graph_name, readonly)
   1014         rt.wait_until_updated()
   1015 else:
-> 1016     self.refresh_routing_table(graph_name)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/__init__.py:1064, in Connector.refresh_routing_table(self, graph_name)
   1062                 cx.release()
   1063     else:
-> 1064         raise ServiceUnavailable("Cannot connect to any known routers")
   1065 finally:
   1066     rt.set_not_updating()

ServiceUnavailable: Cannot connect to any known routers
```

Appreciate any help in resolving this. Thank you!